# Java output lines with each lines containing two string

Tags: java

I want to outpot the N lines with each lines containing either Mary or Jobert. I only know how to loop it but I don't know how it would stop based on the N number

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      int n= 5;
      
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
      
        System.out.println("Mary ");
       
      }
       for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
          System.out.println("Jobert");
       
      }

    }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Mary 
Jobert
Mary 
Mary 
Jobert
Jobert
Mary 
Mary 
Mary 
Jobert
Jobert
Jobert
Mary 
Mary 
Mary 
Mary 
Jobert
Jobert
Jobert
Jobert
```

but what I want is that it would stop at 5 words since n is 5

```
Mary 
Jobert
Mary 
Mary 
Jobert
```

Comment: Increase a counter each time you print a line, and use its value compared to `n`  with `&&` in the conditions of each of your loops.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand my english is not that good.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Do you mean each line should randomly print either Mary or Jobert? It so You need `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try below code :

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        int n = 7;
        int counter = 0;
      
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                if(j > 1) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("Mary ");
                }
                
                if(counter == n) {
                    break;
                }
            }
       
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
                if(k > 1) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("Mary ");
                }
                
                if(counter == n) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. it will solve your problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      int n= 5;
      
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i=i+2) {
      for (int j = 1; j < i; j=j+2) {
      
        System.out.println("Mary ");
       
      }
       for (int k = 1; k < i; k=k+4) {
          System.out.println("Jobert");
       
      }

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in this way using 2 loops only

```
    int n=5;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=5;i++){

        int twice = i*2;
        for(int j = 1 ; j<=twice;j++){

            if(counter == n)
                return;
            if(j<=twice/2) {
                System.out.println("Mary");
                counter++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Jobert");
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```